# CSS first-child absolutely not working

Tags: html, css

I have these html elements:

```css
.form-group:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#form-group:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#my-form #form-group:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#my-form .form-group:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">first</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">second</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group"></div>
</form>
```

And none of these work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: its freaking out because you cannot have more than one id name per element

Comment: ID's must be UNIQUE

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqjust4y/2/ - Looks like it works to me. I put it into a jsfiddle. the only number not displaying is the first child

Comment: I removed all the ids and it still did not work

Comment: All of those look correct. Is there another style sheet that's affecting this? Here's a fiddle that shows the first one is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/w0ghvm53/3/ - edit with removed ids.

Comment: .form-group:nth-of-type(1) {display: none;} would also achieve the same thing

Comment: while your html is invalid but I don't see why your first rule wouldn't work, I edited the question and put it into a snippet and as you can see it works

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/05ohyw7q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, ID's should be unique but

```
#my-form .form-group:first-child {

display: none;
}
```

..will work regardless

```css
#my-form .form-group:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">1</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">2</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">3</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">4</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">5</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">6</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">7</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">8</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">9</div>
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group">10</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Then you have something else going on...it clearly **does** work

Comment: Maybe you have a `display:block` in your code that your not sharing with us that overrides the display none

Comment: Probably angular is displaying it with inline css

Comment: @Huangism OP hasn't mentioned Angular but inline CSS would do it I suspect. Without the **actual** code though we can only go by what the OP provides. </shrug/>

Comment: Yea it was just a thought, the form-group gives it away but something is definitely interfering with it

Answer (score 0):

All those variations should work. You probably have an error in your `<style>` or `<link>` tag, or a problem with the document loading and referencing an external stylesheet.

Examples of correct syntax:

Referencing an external stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

Or an inline stylesheet.

```
<style>
.form-group:first-child {
    display: none;
}

#form-group:first-child {
    display: none;
}

#my-form #form-group:first-child {
    display: none;
}

#my-form .form-group:first-child {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```